# Запись из переменной в базу с другой формы value

Tags: php, form, submit

Всем пис. 
Есть 2 формы и 2 сабмита.

```
<form id="1">
 <input id="1" name="alehsa-1" value="1"></input>
 <input id="1" name="alehsa-2" value="2"></input>
</form>
```

и

```
<form id="2">
 <input id="3" name="alehsa-3" value="3"></input>
 <input id="4" name="alehsa-4" value="4"></input>
</form>
```

При нажатии на сабмит формы 1 данные добавляются из инпута 1 и 2, а при нажатии на сабмит формы 2 данные 3 и 4 но нужно к ним добавить ещё данные из первой формы из инпута id-1. Как это всё провернуть ибо деревянный по уши. Заранее спасибо за готовое решение

Answer (score 1):

Отправка данных одной копкой типа submit из разных форм невозможна.
Можно осуществить это другими способами:

Простое и дешёвое решение:
Сделайте всё одной формой. А в принимающем скрипте используйте те значения, которые требуется.

Сложное и дорогое решение:
Сделайте в формах скрытые поля, в которые через JS будете копировать пользовательский ввод.

Answer (score 0):

По-быстрому можно сделать с помощью JavaScript и jQuery:

По событию `submit` любой из форм выполнить их сериализацию с помощью `jQuery.serialize` и с помощью служебного объекта JavaScript `window.location` перезагрузить страницу с параметрами форм.

Соответственно, если вам нужно перейти на другую страницу, адрес нужно указать перед знаком вопроса `"?"`

```
 <form id="f1" class="s-form">
  <input id="i1" name="alehsa-1" value="1">
  <input id="i2" name="alehsa-2" value="2">
  <input type="submit">
 </form>

 <form id="f2" class="s-form">
  <input id="i3" name="alehsa-3" value="3">
  <input id="i4" name="alehsa-4" value="4">
  <input type="submit">
 </form>

 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script>
 jQuery('.s-form').submit(function () {
    window.location.search = "?" + jQuery(".s-form").serialize();
 });
 </script>
```

Помните что аттрибут "id" должен быть уникальным на странице. Этим он и отличается от аттрибута "class"

Comment: Это типа переменные из двух форм вытягивает в общак?

Comment: Да, и отправляет на страницу, передавая эти параметры как $_GET.